# WordPress Redirect Old URLs - Remove Category

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

before

```
sample.com/info/news-in-one.html
sample.com/tests/test-for-me.html
sample.com/matrix/pro-matrix.html
and more
```

after

```
sample.com/news-in-one.html
sample.com/test-for-me.html
sample.com/pro-matrix.html
and more
```

And I want to redirect old urls. How can I do that in htaccess.

Total categories 6: info, tests, matrix, notes, ground, sea.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You want to rewrite or redirect? Should the URL change in the browser? Should it be for everything in those directories? info, tests and matrix?

Comment: I want to redirect. I changed the link structure (deleted categories of urls). Total categories 6: info, tests, matrix, notes, ground, sea.

Comment: Thanks, I updated your question with that info and provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?:info|tests|matrix|notes|ground|sea)/(.+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these links stopped working:

`sample.com/info/
sample.com/tests/
sample.com/matrix/
sample.com/notes/
sample.com/ground/
sample.com/sea/`

These references lists of articles

Comment: Thank you. But I was faced with this problem:

`sample.com/info/page/2/
sample.com/info/page/3/
sample.com/info/page/4/
...
sample.com/tests/page/2/
sample.com/tests/page/3/
sample.com/tests/page/4/
...
and more`

Comment: And what do you want them to redirect to? Please update your question with the information.

Comment: The language barrier prevents competently explain. I want to redirect the pages of articles (they end in .html). A category page redirect is not necessary.

Comment: I updated the rule so it will only redirect if they end in `.html`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very grateful for their assistance. Now everything works as it is necessary :-)